# Getting a database error when publishing a DCP

Tags: 2011, publishing, database

I have been trying to publish a Dynamic Component Presentation but for some reason it keeps on failing with the following error:

> A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure
>   "EDA_ITEMS_UPDATE"

Has anyone else come across this error before?

Screenshot:

[image: A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS_UPDATE".]

Comment: Check your storage config, is ComponentPresentation mapped there?

Comment: Yes. I just verified, the ComponentPresentation is mapped in the Storage configuration.

Answer (score 6):

`EDA_ITEMS_UPDATE` is a CM-side stored procedure, so your error is not on the delivery side. I would:

- Try rendering the same component with a different template
- Try rendering a different component with the same template

And then try to derive some conclusions from those results. Potentially create a new template with the same TBBs and try rendering that? It could be something wrong with the data from an upgrade script?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check Event Logs (Application Log - Tridion and Tridion Content Manager Logs) on the CMS Server; is there any other more illustrated error or warning?